# Is it a good practice to create and use String objects for locking in thread synchronization?

Tags: java, string, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

*Sorry for my English*

I don't use any of fields for the locking because so I shouldn't think about could or couldn't some field have value `null`.

I always create special fields used only for locking in thread synchronization.

For example:

```
public class Worker {

    private static final List<Toilet> TOILETS = Arrays.asList(
        new Toilet(1),
        new Toilet(2),
        // ...
        new Toilet(NUMBER_OF_FLOORS)
    );

    // here it is:
    private static final List<String> LOCK_TOILETS = Arrays.asList(
        "LOCK TOILET #1",
        "LOCK TOILET #2",
        // ...
        "LOCK TOILET #" + NUMBER_OF_FLOORS
    );

    private final int floorNumber;

    public void spendWorkingHours() {
        for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i) {
            doWork();
            snackSomething();
            String lockToilet = LOCK_TOILETS.get(floorNumber);
            Toilet theOnlyToiletOnTheFloor = TOILETS.get(floorNumber);
            synchronized (lockToilet) {
                goToToilet(theOnlyToiletOnTheFloor);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You should synchronize on the actual object you're using, in this example the toilet.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström what if this variable could be `null` ?

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström No, You shouldn't. It add extra constraints. Imagine other independent part of program do the sme. It cause that two independent part will interfere

Comment: @talex what do you mean by "interfere"? Isnt the goal to prevent a race condition on toilet objects? This mutual exclusion "interference" is what will keep the program safe.

Comment: @UmNyobe Maybe yes. But imagine that I lock on toilet but work with different object.

Comment: @talex: That is the point of synchronization, to prevent other parts of the program from using the object while you're using it.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström yes. but you can use same object for **independent** task. It is better to have dedicated object to lock on.

Comment: @talex: Ideally an object should do one thing and do it well. If it has to do different things for different threads, it should handle its own locking or provide locks to use.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström, what happens when the invariant that the lock is supposed to protect is a relationship between two or more objects?  Which one would you lock?

Comment: @jameslarge: I would lock on the object representing the relationship between the objects.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström, Ooo!  Good answer.  I had not thought about it that way.  Only,  sometimes the "object representing the relationship" either (A) has no state or methods of its own, or (B) is public.  I don't like to use a public object as a lock if the data to be locked are private.

Comment: Objects aren't public, references are. If you don't have a suitable object to act as the lock, make one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not use `String`s for lock objects especially not *string literals*.

String literals are from the `String` pool and each `String` literal which is the same string is the *same* reference. This means if 2 different threads use 2 "different" string literals are actually the same and hence deadlock can easily occur.

To demonstrate:

```
// Thread #1
String LOCK1 = "mylock";
synchronized (LOCK1) {
}

// Thread #2
String LOCK2 = "mylock";
synchronized (LOCK2) {
    // This is actually the SAME lock,
    // might cause deadlock between the 2 synchronized blocks!
    // Because LOCK1==LOCK2!
}
```

Best would be to synchronize on private objects which are not accessible from the "outside". If you use an `Object` for lock which is visible from "outside" (or returned by a method), that object is available to anyone to also use as a lock which you have no control over and may cause a deadlock with your internal `synchronized` block.
For example you can synchronize on the object you whish to guard if it is private, or create a private, internal lock `Object`:

```
private final Object LOCK = new Object();

// Later:
synchronized (LOCK) {
    // LOCK is not known to any "outsiders", safe to use it as internal lock
}
```

Comment: What if we lock on string which is private and final. private final String lock="somevalue"; This string is not used anywhere apart from the purpose of locking.Should we do this?

Comment: @beinghuman It's not different. If you use a string literal to initialize it, and if someone else also uses the same string literal, it will still be the same reference. This is covered / guaranteed by the language spec.

Comment: Your answer is quite confusing.Please be a little bit clear.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `String` may not be the best idea, because this class gets a bit of special treatment, and strings with the same contents may be reused (so locking a toilet on the first floor would also lock the toilet with the same number on the other floors).

Your best choice here is locking the actual toilet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `lockToilet` why don't you just use a [synchronized statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) over each `TOILET` resource?

```
Toilet t;
syncrhonized(TOILETS)
{
     t = = TOILETS.get(floorNumber);
}

synchronized (t) {
            goToToilet(t);
 }
```

`syncrhonized` In this code means that any use of the object between parentheses is thread exclussive within the scope between brakets thus this object becoming a lock.

Answer (score 1):

Answers do cover your question regarding the use of Strings for locking (See String interning for more details) so I will just mention a few other considerations:

Although you have defined the `List` as `final` (Cannot assign another list instance) and initialized with `.asList(..)` (Cannot change size) this doesn't make read-only or `thread-safe`, so if someone changes elements in that list you might get into an unstable state. Consider using a read-only list.

You also need to clarify the scope of locking. What are you trying to lock against? If `goToToilet` changes the object attributes, then the point of synchronization would be better placed in the method that changes the state of the `Object`. (This is a design recommendation; The code would work but would also be prone to errors when changing the code in the future)

Finally, I would also have a look in java `concurrent` structures as you might find concurrent collections and locking mechanisms useful.